# Mac App Store purchases are missing

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

When I click on the tab **Purchases** in the Mac App Store, I'm missing purchases that I've never removed.

How can I get them back to show in the purchase history?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Mac App Store go to...

1. **Store → View my account**
2. In the section **iTunes in the Cloud** click on **View hidden Purchases**.
3. Choose which purchases you want to unhide.

Comment: +1 It is also possible that the developer has removed the app from the store.  In that case, it should be removed from the Purchased list (this has happened to me).

Answer (score 0):

Not only have developers removed apps from the store causing customers to have their product deprecate or disappear, but Apple themself have removed stuff too, such as OS X server, renaming it to 'Server' and causing all customers who previously purchased the app, to lose their app, and their money when updating their os. This happened with iPhoto and Aperture for a while, and my latest purchase to disappear is Feral Interactive's Tomb Raider Underworld, which appears in my Purchased items list, but cannot download, because the app does not exist in the appstore anymore.
The problem is, none of us can afford lawyers to litigate, if not, we could sue Apple for millions for fraudulent services

Comment: update - they have placesd osx server version 3 back in the appstore, with download button, but it doesnt work for El Capitan, because the OS is too 'New'. It also isn't actually available for review either (no reviews tabe or related tab) Aperture also appears, but isnt available for download.